# Typescript + Vue + Element-ui

Tags: typescript, vue.js, element, typescript-typings

How do I use element-ui with Vue+typescript

There are no types for element-ui so when I import it

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Element from 'element-ui'
```

I get an error

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'element-ui'. '/home/andres/Code/cdr/frontend/node_modules/element-ui/lib/element-ui.common.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

How do I work around this?

Comment: Can you add your typescript config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a workaround you can simply create a custom typings file and declare the module:

```
// in element-ui.d.ts

declare module "element-ui";
```

This will result in anything you import from `element-ui` to be typed as `any`. Of course you can add type definitions in your `element-ui.d.ts` to have typings if you want.

You can [see how to write your own types here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html).